# Handling special characters in html form autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html

I followed this w3schools tutorial to build a form autocomplete (full code on the link):

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete

The problem is every item in the list that contains the ' character is not rendered correctly. I thought I made a mistake but in the example code the same problem happens for "Timor L'Este" rendered as "Timor L".

Escaping ' does not seem to work. Could anyone provide a solution?

Comment: The code you provided through the link works just fine for me in Google Chrome... not sure what the issue is. Are you sure that you've followed the tutorial correctly?

Comment: That's a quote problem in the original code. Try putting escaped double quotes on this line after `value=`: `b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value=\"" + arr[i] + "\">";`

Comment: @Brent Meeusen Even in chrome, clicking Timor L'Este (typing only tim) in the list renders Timor L in the input field. Do you mean it's not the same for you?

Comment: It has to be the same for Brent. It's a code problem, not a browser problem. The HTML string ends up like this `value='Timor L'Este'`

Comment: @ Blex That solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @YannickKilberger I misunderstood you, I thought it was solely about the text that appeared upon typing `Timor`. It shows it correctly in the list, but when I click it, it does only add `Timor L` instead of `Timor L'este` indeed. Sorry for the confusion!